# How to handle empty selection in a JFace bound combobox?

Tags: java, data-binding, combobox, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am developing a search dialog in my eclipse-rcp application.

In the search dialog I have a combobox as follows:

```
comboImp = new CCombo(grpColSpet, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboImp.setBounds(556, 46, 184, 27);
comboImpViewer = new ComboViewer(comboImp);
comboImpViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
comboImpViewer.setInput(ImpContentProvider.getInstance().getImps());
comboImpViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        return ((Imp)element).getImpName();
    }
});
```

`Imp` is a database entity, ManyToOne to the main entity which is searched, and `ImpContentProvider` is the model class which speaks to embedded sqlite database via jpa/hibernate.

This combobox is supposed to contain all instances of `Imp`, *but to also let empty selection*; it's value is bound to a service bean as follows:

```
IObservableValue comboImpSelectionObserveWidget = 
    ViewersObservables.observeSingleSelection(comboImpViewer);
IObservableValue filterByImpObserveValue = 
    BeansObservables.observeValue(searchPrep, "imp");
bindingContext.bindValue(comboImpSelectionObserveWidget, filterByImpObserveValue
    , null, null);
```

As soon as the user clicks on the combo, a selection (first element) is made: I can see the call to a selectionlistener i added on the viewer. My question is:

- after a selection has been made, how do I let the user change his mind and have an empty selection in the combobox? should I add a "fake" empty instance of Imp to the List returned by the `ImpContentProvider`? or should I implement an alternative to `ArrayContentProvider`?

and one additional related question is:

- why calling `deselectAll()` and `clearSelection()` on the combo does NOT set a null value to the bound bean?

Comment: Interesting!!..Looks like an issue. for your problem, Can you set "imp" value to null in the Bean? It will clear comboviewer selection as it is bound to comboviewer selection

Comment: if I set "imp" to null in the bean the combo is correctly set to empty selection; however i want a gui way to set that to empty (besides a "clear form" button which I already have).

Comment: Correct. try setting empty selection on Comboviewer, it will fire selectionevent with null value.

Comment: @sambi reddy sorry I cannot understand your last comment. Let me clarify: I want the user to click on an empty item in the combo, making the selection empty and the bean property null. (I can already do it programmatically, but I need it to be done in gui)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ComboViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY)` will fire selection event and set "imp" to null. Combo widget selection event is only triggered when manually selected from dropdown list i think.

**Use Converter**

Define empty selection obj, let us say EMPTYEnum ( display empty string in label provider)

You can define `UpdateValueStrategy` for target-to-model and set `IConverter` when you bind observables. 
In the converter, you can convert EMPTYEnum to null.

```
IConverter:
fromType: Object.class
toType: Object.class

public Object convert(Object fromObject)
{
    if(fromObject instanceof EMPTYEnum)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return fromObject;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the selection should be set on the viewer and not on the contained combo. BUT, my question is: what to put in the dropdown (along entity instances coming from db) to let the user click this empty selection and fire the event?

Comment: thanks we are getting closer! which component should had the enum to the list of entities coming from database? i find it inelegant to add it in the ImpContentProvider.

Comment: I would suggest to extend content provider and override getElements() and add EmptyEnum as first element if input is not empty. I assume you are fetching db content in separate eclipse job or thread to not to block the UI.

Comment: yep; where would you start extending? or you mean implementing  IStructuredContentProvider in a new class? because ArrayContentProvider has "This class is not intended to be subclassed by clients" restriction

Comment: yes. use IStructuredContentProvider. In getElements() method, add EmptyEnum as first element if your input is not empty.

Comment: ok did it, it's working nicely, thanks again. I had to make an  implementation of IConverter using generics, because the arraylists coming from provider are typed.

Answer (score 3):

make LabelProvider and handle null value

```
public String getText(Object element) {
    if (element == null) { 
        return "Choose one"; 
    }
    return super.getText(element);
}
```

insert null value at index 0 and handle empty selection

```
    combo.setInput(yourItems);
    combo.insert(null, 0);
    combo.getCCombo().select(0);
    combo.addPostSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            if (combo.getCCombo().getSelectionIndex() == -1) {
                combo.getCCombo().select(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

bind ComboViewer ...